# How to get the .env file into the remote host server

Tags: django, environment-variables, gitignore

Quick question how to get the .env conf file into the server.
I have three settings file in my project base, development, production. *I think testing and staging is an overkill*

It is encouraged to put .env in .gitignore file. so it won't be included in version control. in Heroku, it is easy to set the environment variable in the settings tab. what about other hosting services without such a feature? since I push to my repository and pull from the server, How I am I suppose to get the API keys stored in the .env since it will ignore it (it's in gitignore) file? should I create in the server? or is there a way it is done? Newbie question I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct. You should put your `.env` file in `.gitignore` and create `.env` file on server manually - either by connecting to server (SSH) and creating file or transfer file using one of secure transfer protocols (SCP, SFTP).

Answer (score 0):

exact command you need to run is (in root directory of your project)

```
touch .env.local
nano .env.local
```

then paste with ctrl+shift+v your env variables
then press ctrl+o - enter - ctrl+x